# Is it possible to code multiple pseudos in one curly bracket in css?

Tags: css, href

When styling links, using pseudos multiple times looks a bit ugly and time-consuming.
Is this possible when styling links or are there any easier and good-looking ways than this?
For example:

```
a:hover,:visited {
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things readable in CSS is similar to having a long line of code in any other programming language. I tend to rather break multiple CSS selectors into individual lines, so they're readable but still share the same style:

```
a:hover,
a:visited,
... {
    // your styles
}
```

but when doing the same in any CSS preprocessor i.e. SCSS, you could do this in other ways, but may not be any better than the above.

```
a {
    &:hover,
    &:visited {
        // basically even more verbose
    }
}
```

or maybe even:

```
$pseudos: 'hover', 'visited', 'active';
$each $p in $pseudos {
    a:{$p} {
        // same styles but overall even more verbose
    }
}
```

I would stick to the first one anyway. It's the most terse and readable of all unless of course there would be other styles related to general A element. In this case I'd use second notation, because the parent A style container would contain even more diverse A-related styles. This would be an example:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $default;

    &.pop-out:after {
        // just an example, which I'd rather solve using an icon font
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        background-image: url(popout-icon.png);
    }

    &:hover,
    &:visited {
        // pseudo specials go here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the second part of your selector `a:hover,:visited` would actually mean this:

```
*:visited { ... }
```

So it would not only apply to `a` tags, but to *all* tags (although I don't think there are any other tags where `visited` could apply)

Back to the question, I always group the rules like this:

```
a:link, a:visited {
  [settings]
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  [settings]
}
```

...and it works well